# Occult Research for azathoth on Eldritch Horror

Tags: eldritch-horror

One occult research card for Azathoth states that in order to solve it, you must research Clue tokens found across the map. In a game just finished, I did a clue research and gained a clue but failed the overall encounter. Could I still place the clue I gained on the occult research card even though I failed the overall encounter?

The description for the occult research card is:

> After an investigation resolves a research encounter, he may spend 1
>   Clue he gained form that encounter and place that clue on this card. 
>   At the end of the Mythos Phase, if there are Clues on this card equal
>   to the number of investigators, solve this Mystery.

Comment: "gained a clue but failed the overall encounter" - if you gained the Clue how have you determined the failure?

Comment: @tsuma534 gained a clue before having to roll the die to determine if I passed a test. I failed the die roll and picked up an injury. The prize for passing the test was something else which I don't recall now.

Comment: You failed the test, but not the encounter. See http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/33887/14416

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, resolving the encounter doesn't mean you have to resolve it successfully. Your clue gained during the encounter still entitles you to place it, as the Mystery states.

A few references to illustrate that the term **resolve** doesn't imply success or passing a test:

On page 9 of the rulebook, when describing Phase 2, the Encounter Phase:

> During this phase, each investigator resolves one encounter.... is phase starts with the Lead Investigator. He resolves an encounter, then the investigator to his left resolves an encounter, and so on, until each investigator has resolved one encounter.

Under Token Encounters on the same page:

> Clue tokens allow investigators to draw and resolve Research Encounter cards.
>
> Gate tokens allow investigators to draw and resolve Other World Encounter cards.
>
> Active Expedition token allows investigators to draw and resolve Expedition Encounter cards.

On Page 12 under Complex Encounters:

> Expedition Encounters, Other World Encounters, and Special Encounters are rewarding but dangerous adventures called complex encounters. Each of these cards has three effects. To resolve these encounters, an investigator first resolves the initial effect (the top box of the card). Depending upon the result of this effect, he immediately resolves one of the other two effects.

These examples illustrate that resolving doesn't imply success, as the last case even talks of resolving and then branching based on the result of the effect (implying that 'resolve' could be a success or failure).

Comment: Any source quotes to support this answer?

Comment: Is there a specific aspect of the question or answer you would like to see documentation for?  The term "resolve" is used numerous times in the EH documentation to make it clear that it's synonymous with "complete" and not "complete successfully".  The wording in the quote within the question seems straightforward to me "he may spend 1 Clue he gained" etc.  Wherein lies the lack of clarity?

Comment: I have read the rules and did not make this connection, so quoting one of the "numerous times" and referencing a page would be helpful I think.  I'd like to read it for myself and not hunt for it tho I can if you can't quote=)

Comment: I'm happy to throw a few references into my answer, just wanted to be sure there weren't other aspects people wanted references to. I will edit it soon.

Answer (score 2):

Eldritch Horror doesn't have a concept of failing or succeeding at an encounter.

Occult Research only cares whether you gained a Clue from a Research Encounter. It doesn't care if you were Injured along the way, had to sign a Dark Pact or did anything else which might be thematically considered a failure.